# $f(x)=\tan x$ for rationals, $f(x)=x^2+1$ for irrationals At exactly how many points will $f(x)$ be continuous within $[0, 6 \pi]$

Tags: calculus, continuity

$f(x)=\tan x$ for rationals, 
$f(x)=x^2+1$ for irrationals At exactly how many points will $f(x)$ be continuous within $[0, 6 \pi]$

I got the answer as $6$,am I correct?

Comment: How did you get 6?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, since the only points where continuity occurs is when the functions are equal (because both of them are continuous when they intersect), that is, when their graphs intersect (by density arguments). And the graphs intersect once in every $(n\pi, n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2})$. So for $n=\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ we have $6$ points.

You can predict that either by looking at the graph, or else by noting that $\tan x$ increases very fast - faster than any polynomial. It goes from $0$ to $\infty$ in every $\frac{\pi}{2}$. Hence, everytime $\tan x$ goes into $(n\pi, n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2})$ you get one point of intersection since $x^2+1$ is still finite. (This is a non-rigorous version of *Intermediate Value Theorem*)

It follows that there are 6 points.

How did CMI go? ;)